# Trivial conversion in overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

Lets consider following class:

```
struct T {
    T() {}
    T(T&) {cout << "1";}
    T(const T&) {cout << "2";}
};
```

Why `T::T(T&)` matches better than `T::T(const T&)` in following initialization:

```
T a;
T b = a;
```

Both overloaded copy ctors requires only trivial conversions, so why there is no ambiguity?

Comment: Because you didn't created your variable as an const variable, but the compiler can cast from non-const to const, Is somehow equals to the overload char* and string then you use f("asd") the compiler can use both

Comment: Looks like I found the answer in standard in section 13.3.3.2/3 [over.ics.rank]: `Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion and yield similar types T1 and T2 respectively, and the cv-qualification signature of type T1 is a proper subset of the cv-qualification signature of type T2`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this table help you little bit:

| Convert from Type | Convert to Type |
| --- | --- |
| type-name | type-name & |
| type-name & | type-name |
| type-name [ ] | type-name * |
| type-name ( argument-list ) | ( * type-name ) ( argument-list ) |
| type-name | const type-name |
| type-name | volatile type-name |
| type-name * | const type-name * |
| type-name * | volatile type-name * |

Refer: [Ref-qualifiers on member functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-overloading?view=msvc-160#ref-qualifiers)

Comment: I have tried editing it into a table. Please make any corrections if I missed anything

Comment: The link is irrelevant, also can't make head nor tail of this table.

Comment: This link contain info about the function overloading and on that we have info about trivial conversion.

Comment: In that case, link to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-overloading?view=msvc-160#argument-matching-and-conversions.

Comment: @AbhishekDimri I would suggest that you add as much detail in your answers as possible. Please explain how this table and link help in this scenario.